# Use closure to pass data between two controllers

Tags: swift, closures

my problem looks so simple, but since I am a beginner, I have problem to understand the concept of the closure to pass data between two controllers

for example I have a static table view controllers that has one cell and a title inside it

```
class FirstView: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
```

and I have an another view controller that contain a button inside it

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func pressChangeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

}
```

and there is segue1 between these two controllers, with identifier "segue1"

I want a to a simple task, I want to add a `boolean` closure that it will be `true` if the change button is pressed. 
that is why I create a closure function the second view controller that has change button.

```
var change : ((Bool) -> Void)?
```

I just want, that the second view controllers tells the first one that change closure is now true (after pressing the change button) and the first view controllers simply change the title table inside it to whatever (I just want to see that how it can be done)

I don't know I have to use prepare sugue function?
Could anyone help me to understand this concept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
class FirstView: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func goToSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: nil)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "segue1" {
            let des = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            des.change = { [weak self] (value) in
                print(value)
                self?.titleLabel.text = "SetValue"// set a value
            }
        }
    }

}
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var change : ((Bool) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func pressChangeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        change?(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A closure is basically a piece of code that you can run. In Swift a closure is a first class citizen as it can be passed around as parameters and return type of functions. That being said, you can pass or set a closure as you normally would for other objects.

As per Sh_Kan's answer, just set `SecondViewController`'s closure in `prepare(for segue:sender:)`, always paying extra attention to [retain cycles](https://www.raywenderlich.com/959-arc-and-memory-management-in-swift). You might also want to take a look at **delegate** design pattern in order to exchange data and messages between your controllers.